# System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Invoice__c.CurrencyIsoCode

Tags: apex, managed-package, multi-currency, currencyisocode

I am trying to get the `CurrencyIsoCode` from an object, but I don't know if `Multi-Currency` is enabled, because my code is part of a managed package.

```
private static String getCurrencyIsoCode(SObject someObject){
    return UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization() ? (String) someObject.get('CurrencyIsoCode') : UserInfo.getDefaultCurrency();
}
```

Because I don't know if `Multi-Currency` is enabled, I don't add `CurrencyIsoCode` to my `SOQL` query.

Therefore, when I run the above method, I am getting the below error:

> System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Invoice__c.CurrencyIsoCode

**Question**

1. How can I get `CurrencyIsoCode` when it's available?
2. Do I need two different `SOQL` queries or is there another approach?

But when

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily need two queries. For example, you might do this:

```
String[] fields = 'Id,Name,CustomField1__c'.split(',');
if(someSObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey('CurrencyIsoCode')) {
  fields.add('CurrencyIsoCode');
}
SObject[] records = Database.query('SELECT '+String.join(fields,',')+' FROM '+someSObjectType+' WHERE '+filters);
```

For the getCurrencyIsoCode function:

```
if(someObject.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().containsKey('CurrencyIsoCode')) {
  return (String)someObject.get('CurrencyIsoCode');
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a pain to have to jump through hoops like this. I think `CurrencyIsoCode` should always be there... but be either null or set to the org default

Comment: @Robs I concur. If we were talking about features, I'd also love to see RecordTypeId always be available. No reason why it can't return null if there are no record types.

Comment: Would you recommend `someSObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey('CurrencyIsoCode')` over using `UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization()`?

Comment: @Robs Depends on the use case. Even in a multi-currency org, not all objects will have this field. If you're using some sort of generic query builder design, check for the field. If you're limited to just certain objects that you know ahead of time, isMultiCurrencyOrganization will be faster.